# MongoDB Container Docker not working. MacOS

Tags: docker, mongodb, docker-compose

Any time I try to access my container it shows the path isn't found?
I get this error

"mongo": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

How can I fix this?

[Docker-compose file and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyevz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You trying run `mongo` command inside container named mongo.

- maybe it's just a typo and you dont wanna run any command inside container
- maybe it's typo in command name, check name of executable you need, maybe you want run mongodb or something else
- add path where executable is into $PATH variable inside container
- move executable into the path listed in $PATH variable inside container

Do your practice well - read the docs:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/